# Add RSA key to Android project in a secure way

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key, public-key

In my Android project a need to cypher and decypher RSA values.
I have both private & public RSA keys in *.pem files.
I have added it to the project but when I  try to create the release apk, lint says:

> Error:Error: The raw/private_key.pem file seems to be a private key file. Please make sure not to embed this in your APK file. [PackagedPrivateKey]
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
>
> > Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.   To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your
> >     build script as follows:   ...   android {
> >           lintOptions {
> >               checkReleaseBuilds false
> >               // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
> >               // but continue the build even when errors are found:
> >               abortOnError false
> >           }   }   ...

I have tried to find the right way to add the keys to the project without success.

Any help on how to add the keys properly?
Thanks.

Comment: If a private key is added to a publicly available zip file (that's what an APK is), then anybody can use your private key to do all kinds of stuff. What is it that you want to achieve? Perhaps you should rethink your design.

Comment: This is simply a design flaw.  You should never need to include a private key in an apk.